# StateFull Widget Error - Classes can only extend other classes

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

[image: flutter doctor]
[image: code 1]
[image: code 2]
I keep getting this error from my statefullwidget (Classes can only extend other classes.). I have also attched the status of my flutter doctor.
I have updated my flutter app, I have also run flutter clean & flutter pub get but I am keep having that issue.

Comment: Please provide direct images in place of links